# What is equivalent GAE cron expression for following

Tags: google-app-engine

```
I have spring cron equation.
I need equivalent GAE cron for those.
GAE cron doc seems bit complex.
cron="0 0 7 * * MON-FRI"
cron="0 30 9 * * "SUN"
```

I need equivalent GAE cron for those

Comment: Try `schedule: every mon,tue,wed,thu,fri 07:00` and `every sun 09:30`

Comment: Thanks a lot GAEfan ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new file called cron.xml into WEB-INF folder. For example this cron runs the url indicated every 5 days, but you can also configure the schedule format.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/url</url>
        <description>Information about cron job</description>
        <schedule>every 24 hours</schedule>
    </cron>
</cronentries>
```

The complete reference is here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

Here examples about change schedule format:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml